# Cardinality of infinite direct sum of Z/2Z

Tags: cardinals

Consider the direct sum of countably many Z/2Z groups, which I'll denote by
G=$⨁_n $(Z/2Z)
and where the index is to keep track of each copy of Z/2Z.
How is G countable? Since each Z/2Z has 2 elements,is not the cardinality 2^No?

Comment: I am unable to use the proper mathjax code to edit my question.

Comment: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to distinguish between the direct **product** and the direct **sum**. Informally, the elements of the direct product are *arbitrary* sequences of elements from $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$, while the direct sum consists only of those elements in which *all but finitely many terms are the identity*. E.g. $$(1, 1,1, 1, 1, ...)$$ is an element of the direct product $\prod_\mathbb{N}\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ but not of the direct sum $\bigoplus_\mathbb{N}\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$.

Since $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ only has one nonzero element, an element of the direct product or direct sum is completely determined by *which of its terms are nonzero*. So the question of the cardinality of $\bigoplus_\mathbb{N} \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ boils down to:

> How many finite subsets of $\mathbb{N}$ are there?